# SQL Always Getting Index Scan

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a query in TSQL like this

```
SELECT TOP 10 [e].[id], [e].[Title]
FROM [Table] AS [e]
WHERE (([e].[Confirmed] = 1) AND ([e].[Deleted] = 0)) AND ([e].
[Status] <> 3)
ORDER BY [e].[CreatedOn] DESC
```

whatever index i made i always get and index instead of seek
included, conditional index no matter what i do i always get an index scan

the last thing i tried was

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIXF-x] ON [dbo].[Table]
(
 [CreatedOn] DESC

)
 INCLUDE (  [id],
            [Title] ) 
WHERE ([Confirmed]=(1) AND [Deleted]=(0) AND [Status] !=(3))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = 
ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How can i get an index seek? i have tried everything . why i can't get an index seek?

Comment: Because you don't need an index seek. You're requesting the first 10 rows matching a (non-unique) condition. That's a scan (of 10 rows), even with a covering index. Check how many reads the query actually produces (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`), don't fixate on seek vs. scan. (Also, don't make an index on a column `DESC` -- this is mostly useless as SQL Server can scan the index backwards regardless, and it can cause terrible fragmentation.)

Comment: How big is your table? Sometimes a table scan can be faster than a table seek. Do you do not have a covering index? Also, if your table is small or you have a large number or matches then a scan will be faster.

Comment: its about 70 million rows

Answer (score 0):

Index is a tree and index scan is tree traversal (selecting first/last nodes) - exactly what you want.

Index seek - search in a tree using given predicate (search condition). In your query you have no predicate, that's why it's impossible to get index seek.

You can view a predicate in properties of node of query plan (of course, if it exists)

`WHERE (([e].[Confirmed] = 1) AND ([e].[Deleted] = 0)) AND ([e].
[Status] <> 3)` is not a predicate for your index